# React Native - Best practice for persisting state

Tags: react-native, persistence, state

I'm trying to implement a feature that would show if items have been read or unread in my app. Say for example a user would open a certain unread item, the item is then marked as "read" and it should stay "read" until the app is either uninstalled or the app data is manually cleared.

I'm wondering what would be the best practice for implementing a feature like this. Is there a way I can hold this info in my state, and somehow have my state persist even after the app closes? Or should this be done through AsyncStorage?

Comment: Are you using Redux for state management?

Answer (score 1):

For persisting your store data, try [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) - works pretty well & straightforward. It internally uses `AsyncStorage` as the storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

Where are the items coming from?

How you'd solve this problem depends on your implementation details.

1. Is this an email-like item, where each item is specific to a user? Then the best place to persist state would probably be in the cloud, as part of the item itself. `{messageid: 1, userid: 'xyz', read: true}`
2. Is it a chat-like item, then it's probably also best to persist the state on the server.
3. Is it a mass-notification, then perhaps the best place would be async storage.

Another factor to consider, but not mentioned is how to handle the same 'item' read/unread state across multiple devices. Does it need to be consistent, or could it be read on one device and unread on another?

Regardless of your specific implementation details, I hope this gives you enough to chew on and will point you in the right direction.